# How to teach the concepts of "Electric Potential" & "Potential Energy" to 10th grade students

Tags: energy, electricity

I've got to teach  the concepts of "Electric Potential" & "Potential Energy" to 10th grade students. I don't understand how to express these things and make them understand.

> “If you can't explain it simply, you don't understand it well enough” ~ Albert Einstein

Probably I didn't understand well enough.

Comment: You might find something useful in this website about teaching elementary electricity: http://amasci.com/miscon/elect.html There's one page on teaching voltage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to use the [water storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydraulic_analogy) analogy.

That helps best, even I was taught using that analogy. Even the formulas in both the circumstances matches to some extend.

The Only problem would be when you will be trying to explain the advanced concepts like wave-matter duality they will have to unlearn this analogy because then electrons are no longer like water. But becomes an entirely different beast.